# Getting TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

Trying to plot the decision Boundary of the k-NN Classifier but is unable to do so getting `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key`

```
h = .01  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF','#AFAFAF'])
cmap_bold  = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF','#AFAFAF'])

for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=6, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold)
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("4-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))

plt.show()
```

Got this when running not very sure what it means dont think the clf.fit have a problem but I am not sure

```
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-394-bef9b05b1940> in <module>
     12         # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
     13         # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
---> 14         x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
     15         y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
     16         xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2654                                  'backfill or nearest lookups')
   2655             try:
-> 2656                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2657             except KeyError:
   2658                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring?  I'm assuming at clf.fit.  If so, how is X_train and y_train defined?

Comment: What type is X? Whatever it is doesn't support numpy extended indexing.

Comment: I have also encountered the same error, when plotting covariance matrix. I'm wondering whether anyone came with the solution ?

Answer (score 64):

Since you are trying to access directly as array, you are getting that issue. Try this:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean',verbose=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X.iloc[:, 1:3])
X.iloc[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X.iloc[:, 1:3])
```

Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)/[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 45):

You need to use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)/[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) to acces df. Try adding iloc to X so `X.iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Do we know why `iloc` is needed?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue with the following

```py
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
```

Then I added `.values` property, after that it worked without problem

```py
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
```

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it by converting the pandas dataframe to a numpy array. Got help from [here](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/issues/293)

Answer (score 6):

When you are trying to fetch the dataset using pandas use the below code:

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv("path or file name")
x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
```

Answer (score 6):

When importing the datasets, use .values.

Change:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:3]
```

To:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:3].values
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue when using

```
features = data.iloc[:,:-1]
si = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
si.fit(features[:, 1:])
```

then I solved this by calling **`.values()`** function/method to output of iloc, and then as a numpy.ndarray it worked!

```
features = data.iloc[:,:-1].values()
si = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
si.fit(features[:, 1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Which library did you use to load the dataset?
If you used Pandas library to load the dataset, you need to add an index-based selection (iloc) function  to the data frame in order to access the values, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('../filename.csv')
X=data.iloc[:,0:8]
y=data.iloc[:,8]
```

**For your problem:**

```
x_min, x_max = X.iloc[:, 0].min() - 1, X.iloc[:, 0].max() + 1
```

If you used the NumPy library to load the dataset, you can access the values directly  as an array, e.g.

```
from numpy import loadtxt
data=loadtxt('../filename.csv',delimiter=',')
X=data[:,0:8]
y=data[:,8]
```

**For your problem :**

```
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to create the array

x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1

This is present in the dataframe

you have to first convert the dataframe to array by this
dataframe.values then apply this

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.nan, strategy= 'mean')

imputer = imputer.fit(X.iloc[:, 1:3])
X = imputer.transform(X.iloc[:, 1:3])
```

Comment: you should try this                             
  #Take care of missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.nan, strategy= 'mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(X.iloc[:, 1:3])
X = imputer.transform(X.iloc[:, 1:3])

Answer (score 1):

Try run this code before your code writed above.

```py
x_min = x_min.values
x_min = x_min.astype('float32')
x_max = x_max.values
y_test1 = x_max.astype('float32')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ***.values*** to access dataframe values. For Example

```
df = df[['column_name']].values
```

I hope this will help. You can use it for any case according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I changed my input to a numpy array instead and it worked. I have still not been able to sort this issue with a Pandas dataframe input. If it is urgent in your case, I suggest changing your input to numpy and moving ahead.