# Getting Errors with StandardScaler Python

Tags: pandas

I am trying to scale my training and test data for a Logistic Regression but an error popped-up.

I implemented the answer in this stack: [How to standard scale a 3D matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125844/how-to-standard-scale-a-3d-matrix)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('GonzagaTakers.csv')

x_df=df.loc[:, df.columns !='Remarks_P']
features = x_df.keys()
target = 'Remarks_P'

X = df[features]
y = df[target]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=101)

scalers ={}
for i in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    scalers[i] = StandardScaler()
    X_train[:, :, i]=scalers[i].fit_transform(X_train[:, :, i])

for i in range(y_test.shape[1]):
    y_test[:,:,i]=scalers[i].fit_transform(y_test[:,:,i])


_model = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')

_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = _model.score(X_test, y_test) * 100
```

Error occurs in this line

```
X_train[:, :, i]=scalers[i].fit_transform(X_train[:, :, i])
```

> TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), 0)' is
>   an invalid key

Comment: `X` is a dataframe, which is two dimensional, so you cannot have more than 2 indexes. Plus, you can't do `X[:,:]` either, that works with numpy array `X.values`, not dataframes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291667/getting-typeerror-slicenone-none-none-0-is-an-invalid-key)